# numeraljs vs. numeral.js: Dot or no dot?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Unless I'm sleepy enough, [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) and [numeral.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeral.js) seem to be about the same subject: [A JavaScript library](http://numeraljs.com/) for formatting and working with numbers.

Dotted [numeral.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeral.js) was created [in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30088206/revisions) whereas the plain [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) in [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45169988/revisions). The former has a link to the library's homepage, while the latter has a short paragraph explaining what it does.

The library has its name written as `Numeral.js` on the homepage, so [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) should probably be a synonym.

Could someone privileged enough merge these tags, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given both that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45169487/1) which created the [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) directly links to the Numeral.js site, and that 5 of the 9 questions tagged [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) were also tagged [numeral.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeral.js), I went ahead and merged the two tags with the .js version as the parent tag.

I also created a synonym directing from [numeraljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeraljs) to [numeral.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeral.js) which will prevent someone from creating a dot-less version in future (since it already exists).

If someone is knowledgeable and so inclined to create a better tag wiki excerpt which provides actual usage guidance and a tag wiki which doesn't plagiarise the documentation that'd probably be of value as well.